# Swing show up multiple child jframe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I was doing a project in JAVA Swing Netbeans IDE 7.1. I created one jFrame with  some button and Dropdowns  on it. On selecting a choice from the dropdown,another frame object is created and setVisible is set to true. But instead of showing one window, it is showing up 2 windows. There are other similar calls, but none have this issue, someone please help me. Thanks.

Code:

```
private void itemListItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          

        String item = null;
        String filename = null;
        item = (String) itemList.getSelectedItem();
        if(item=="P"){

            filename="p";
            description.setText("Description:  P");
        }
        else if(item=="A"){

            filename="a";
            description.setText("Description:  A");
        }
        else if(item=="R"){

            filename="r";
            description.setText("Description:  R");
        }

        else if(item=="S"){

            filename="s";
            description.setText("Description:  S");
        }

        else if(item=="X"){
            displayText.setText("");
            x xl = new x();
            xl.setVisible(true);

        }

        else if(item=="Xx"){

            filename="xx";
            description.setText("Description: xx");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("invalid selection.");

        }


        if (item=="X"){
            return;
        }
        else {
             displayText.setText("");

            BufferedReader b = null;
        try {
            b= new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("/home/sfred/"+filename+".mile"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            line = b.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (line != null){
            displayText.append(line + "\n");
            try {
                line=b.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have coded too much so that I dont want to modify much... Kinnda lazy ... ;) .. Could you help me with this please? I have done this before, but this is the first time am getting something like this. :(....

Answer (score 3):

- See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) rather use :

  1) `JDialog`

  2) [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which will allow you to flip between multiple components on a single `JFrame`.
- You cannot compare `String` using `==`operator must use `equals(String s)` or else it wont evaluate correctly

  ```
  if(item.equals("X")) {
  }
  ```
- Rather use `switch` statement (Java 7+) when comparing `String`:

  ```
  switch(item) {
      case "P":
          //do something
      break;

      case "X":
         //do something
      break;

      default:
         //if no match with above was found..
      break;
  }
  ```

Comment: These all say about not using multiple jFrames, could you please help me with the current situation. I am a newbie in java development, Also, when I set System.out.println(); inside a itemChanged event, it prints the text 2 times.!!

Comment: @SF-Red have you done the suggested changes especaily the String comparison, and I also see 2 checks or *X* this might be whats casuing the 2 `System.out.println`s